# angular-cli any way to emitOnError (ignore typescript errors) for a library?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, ng-packagr

I'm well aware of the arguments against this, please spare me the moralizing.

I'm porting an Angular 11 lerna bootstrap monorepo with a bespoke webpack setup to angular-cli and Angular 13.

Because the original project somehow emitted on error, there are like a thousand errors I would have to fix before I could get an angular-cli monorepo to build.

I'm aware of ngx-build-plus, but it only works for applications

The angular-cli team have made it quite clear they have no interest in supporting this option directly, so I need a custom builder. Any leads?